# How to I adjust flooring where two grooves meet up?

Tags: stairs, vinyl-flooring

I am installing my floors and I mistakenly started from the bedroom and came to the hallway. Now I have reached the stairs and when I tried to install the flush stair nose, I noticed that groove is in the opposite direction.

[image]

Comment: A flush stair nose seems like a generally bad idea to begin with. Who can align their entire project with that one molding? It might not even be square enough with the building to avoid visual problems elsewhere.